# Silent while loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop

I am looking to create a bash script that keeps checking a file in directory and perform certain operation on it. I am using while loop, if file does not exists I want that while loop stays quite and keeps on checking condition. Here is what i created but it keeps throwing error that file not found, if file is not there.

```
while [ ! -f /home/master/applications/tmp/mydata.txt ]

do

cat mydata.txt;
rm mydata.txt;

sleep 1; done
```

Comment: Which error appear? Path is correct?

Comment: PHP? where? where is it here?

Comment: Your logic says: "if the file does not exist, `cat` the file"; how can you `cat` a file that does not exist?  if the test is true (ie, file does **NOT** exist) then the next step (`cat mydate.txt`) is going to generate a `file not found` error

Comment: Is the file being regenerated somehow? Did you mean for it to be shown every time it gets recreated?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issue in your implementation:

1. You should use the same (absolute or relative) path in your while loop test statement `[ ! -f $file ]` and in your cat and rm commands.

The `cat` command is looking for the file in the current working directory (`pwd`) and your while statement might be looking somewhere else and hence, your implementation is buggy and won't work as expected if your `pwd` isn't `/home/master/applications/tmp`.

2. You need to move your cat command and rm command after the while block. It doesn't make sense to cat a file if a file doesn't exist. I think your misplaced those commands.

Try this:

```
file="/home/master/applications/tmp/mydata.txt"
while [ ! -f "$file" ]
do
sleep 1
done

cat $file
rm $file
```

**EDIT**

As per suggestion from @Ivan, you could use [until](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-until-loop/) instead of `while` as it suits more to your requirements.

```
file="/home/master/applications/tmp/mydata.txt"
until [ -f "$file" ]; do sleep 1; done

cat $file
rm $file
```

Comment: And i'd suggest to change `while [ ! -f "$file" ]` to `until [ -f "$file" ]`

Answer (score 0):

Making a different assumption than abhiarora, I'll guess maybe you meant for the file to reappear, and you want it shown each time.

```
file=/home/master/applications/tmp/mydata.txt
while :
do if [[ -f "$file" ]]
   then echo "$(<"$file")"
        rm "$file"
   fi
   sleep 1
done
```

This creates an infinite loop. If that's NOT what you wanted, use abhiarora's solution.